# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354)

Tags: flutter, dart

Cuando hago una petición al servidor de desarrollo me arroja el siguiente error.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter ( 6061):      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

El código:

```
     //Login con apirest laravel
     import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

     Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String password) async {

        final url = Uri.https(_url, '/login');
        var pass = generateSha1(generateMd5(password));

        final response = await http.post(url, body: {
          'email': email,
          'password': pass
        });

        print(response.body);
        Map<String, dynamic> decodeData = json.decode(response.body);

        if (decodeData.containsKey('token')) {
          return {'ok': true, 'token': decodeData['token']};
        } else {
          return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': decodeData['error']};
        }
      }
```

Comment: tu servidor tiene algún certificado? es https ?  puedes acceder desde postman o el browser?

Comment: Si, puedo acceder desde postman, aunque valido y el certificado aun esta vigente.

Comment: con que frecuencia te sucede el error? siempre ? o a veces?

Comment: Siempre, y es solo uno, de tres servidores que tenemos de desarrollo

Comment: estas probando desde tu simulador, android/ios o celular?

Comment: Desde el celular android

Comment: Con este mismo codigo, trabajo en el servidor de produccion, y en los dema de desarrollo y me van bien, y en la teoria los tres servidores de desarrollo son un espejo, a nivel de configuracion.

Answer (score 0):

Ubica el archivo de configuración `AndroidManifest.xml` dentro de la carpeta main y agregale el permiso de Internet.

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Debería estar fuera del tag de   `<application` así:

```xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

**Update**

Como lo mencioné en los comments, si ya tenías los permisos de Internet entonces el error era el certificado.

Solo actualízalo y debería de funcionar.

Comment: La app, ya cuenta con los permisos, hacia los otro servidores, las peticiones se realizan sin ninguna novedad.

Comment: entonces parece ser un problema relacionado con el certificado de tu servidor

Comment: gracias por las respuestas, monte un nuevo certificado y me funciona correctamente. :)

Comment: Ya actualice mi respuesta